# How to Find SSAS .sln files from tarbular cude that have been deployed to sql server to SSAS in visual studio

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, ssas-tabular

I have access to tabular cube that have been deployed to SQL Server Analysis Services (in SQL SERVER), But the parckage is that was deployed from is missing(That is the SSAS) and I am trying to find a way to open the cude in SSAS and add additional information to the cude eg columns and tables. 
See screen shot bellow (Just an example)

[image]

Is it possible to export this deployed cube back to SSAS so that I can see the underlying tables and relationship between the tables?
Thanks

Comment: This is a link to a different site, and for an old version of SQL Server, however, I know the functionality still exists for SSIS, so I suspect it does for SSAS: [Creating a Solution File from an Existing SSAS Cube on the Server](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/creating-a-solution-file-from-an-existing-ssas-cube-on-the-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

- In a modern [SSDT-BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15), start a new project
- Navigate to Business Intelligence->Analysis Services
- Click on "Import from Server (Tabular)
- Adjust a tabular model
- Deploy it back to the sever
- (highly recommended) Add a solution to a source control

[image]